# Get Value of Function returning Boolean value outside the function scope

Tags: swift, swift3

i have a function deductCoins

```
func deductCoins() -> Bool {

        if price > coins {
            label.text = String("You dont have enough coins")
            self.view.addSubview(label)
            return false
        }
        if coins >= price {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")

            //this stuff has to do with the purchasing
            BackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            PurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
            label.removeFromSuperview()
            image.removeFromSuperview()
            return true
        }

        return true
    }
```

and this function is used to deduct coins (hence the name) from the UserDefaults Value "Coins" when the user "purchases content" in my game and i need a way to test if the function deductCoins returned true or false depending on the amount of coins the User has compared to the price of the item  (like stated in the code) but i need to test if it returned true or false outside the function scope

**EDIT**

the question is now clearer (P.S. i was tired when i wrote the original )

Comment: What *"works great"* and what does *"i need to determine if multiple values got unlocked or not"* mean?

Comment: question completely unclear ..

Comment: one one can get what are you asking

Comment: i have altered the question to be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way as any other function with a return value.

```
let deducted = deductCoints()
if deducted {
    //function returned true
} else {
   //function returned false
}
```

If you don't want to store the return value, just check it once, you don't even need to store it in a variable.

```
if deductCoins() {
    //function returned true
} else {
   //function returned false
}
```

For more information on functions, check the [Swift Programming Language Guide - Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)